# Azure VM faulted error

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a huge problem in a production VM I was hosting on Azure infrastructure (size, in case it matters is: Standard DS14 (16 Cores, 112 GB memory))

The entire production server has gone offline, stopped reporting to New Relic, and I can't SSH into it either (it times out). I tried restarting the machine from the portal, but got the message:

`The operation '7922f9ed80af7b2c9a9ec5d13f510393' failed: 'The operation cannot be performed because the virtual machine is faulted.'.`

What can I do? This is quite a bind!

p.s. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/ shows all is well

Comment: stop the vm, try to change the size and then start it again , take care of the sizing as you need to correcltly check the number of disks and make sure this is corresponding to what you have now!

Comment: if that doesn't help, try to recreate the vm from the VHD

Comment: did you check the troubleshooting section in the VM's blade? anything in there?

Comment: @techmike2kx: instead of resizing it, I tried restarting it multiple times. One of those times has worked, I'm now online (I hadn't read your recommendation vis-a-vis resizing it).

Comment: @techmike2kx: how do I go about ascertaining what went wrong?? I can post this as a separate question if you'd like to post an elaborate answer.

Comment: Do your VM in an availability set?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT: no I dont have availability set

Comment: @HassanBaig Use availability set could reduce the probability of this occurrence. But existing VM could not add to availability set.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT: oh that's a problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: @HassanBaig an existing classic VM could add to an availability set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue happens on VM's host has fault.

Restart or create a new VM could solve this issue. Resizing the VM moves the VM to a different host server, so if there is an issue with the host that is impacting a VM, resizing it will get it off that host.

You could check whether your VMs in an [availability set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-availability-set). An availability set is a group of virtual machines that are deployed across fault domains and update domains. An availability set makes sure that your application is not affected by single points of failure, like the network switch or the power unit of a rack of servers.